# Dynamic qrcode just like whatsapp web qrcode

Tags: django, qr-code

How can I generate a QR code that updates periodically (every 10 seconds) in a Django web app, similar to how it is done in WhatsApp Web? Are there any packages or code snippets available for this purpose?

Comment: Did you checked this library https://pypi.org/project/django-qr-code/

Comment: So on the same page you want to pull a different QR code? Exactly how does the *data* in the QR code changes, in other words, what time-sensitive part "feeds" the QR?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know the exact details of how the data should change, but this concept is implemented in WhatsApp Web authentication. I have a similar idea where I want to assign scores to employees when they scan a QR code. If the QR code is dynamic and constantly changing, it prevents misuse, as an employee cannot share the QR code with others to scan. By incorporating a token in the QR code data that expires over time, I can ensure its security.